# Change ibeacon(nRF51822 ) to Eddystone beacon

Tags: eddystone

They gave me a couple of ibeacons(nRF51822 of nordic) Chinese and an apk to configure them but I do not find a firmware to install it, I want to change them to eddystone beacons, I tried in many ways but I have not had success, check the documentation to eddystone, nordic, etc. Please help me, I'm a 20 year old boy and I love programming a lot but I'm desperate

Comment: This will not be easy.  Consider that you can buy a new Eddystone beacon for $20 or less.  Are you really up for building your own firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Nordic provides [Beacon Kit](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822-Bluetooth-Smart-Beacon-Kit) based on this chip as a reference design. That includes hardware design as well as firmware you can download and use.